# using the cut command to print the right field

Tags: bash, cut

This is my very short script to display some information about storage volumes:

```
get_ip="$(ssh $1@$2 volume show"
echo "$get_ip"
```

when I run my bash script this is what is spit out to the terminal:

```
Vserver   Volume       Aggregate    State      Type       Size  Available Used%
--------- ------------ ------------ ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- -----
vs_cfm06  Available    aggr_backup_1 online    RW        100GB    66.35GB   33%
vs_cfm06  Discovery    aggr_backup_1 online    RW        100GB    66.35GB   33%
vs_cfm06  Software     aggr_backup_1 online    RW        100GB    65.08GB   34%
vs_cfm06  Template     aggr_backup_1 online    RW        100GB    66.35GB   33%
vs_cfm06  rootvol      aggr_backup_1 online    RW          1GB    972.5MB    5%
vs_cfm06  vol          aggr_backup_1 online    RW          1GB    972.6MB    5%
6 entries were displayed.
```

all I really want is the names of the Volumes:

```
Volume
---------
Available
Discovery
Software
Template
rootvol 
vol
```

What change do I need to make to my command to get only this information?
Many thanks!

Comment: You probably meant `get_ip="$(ssh $1@$2 volume show)"`. That is, you missed the closing `)` after `show`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "$get_ip" | grep -v "entries" | awk '{print $2}'
```

or with cut:

```
echo "$get_ip" | tr -s " " | grep -v "entries" | cut -d " "  -f 2
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! Can I append them each volume name to an array and iterate through it? Sorry I'm new to bash and it's very different to other languages I've used

Comment: Please start a new question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the second column (containing the headers also but not the last line), do use `awk` like this: tell it just to fetch lines containing exactly 8 fields.

```
get_ip="$(ssh $1@$2 volume show)"
echo "$get_ip" | awk 'NF==8{print $2}'
```

#### Test

File `a` contains your given input.

```
$ awk 'NF==8{print $2}' a
Volume
------------
Available
Discovery
Software
Template
rootvol
vol
```